# Why was this question marked as "primarily opinion based"?

Tags: discussion, flagging

[Quantifying the advantages of a modern version control system](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252424/quantifying-the-advantages-of-a-modern-version-control-system)

The question asked

> What I'm trying to find are ***concrete facts*** demonstrating developers
> work more effectively with Git, or ANY modern source control system.

The notice said

> put on hold as primarily opinion-based ...
>
> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Since I was specifically asking for hard evidence, I don't see how this can be seen as an opinion oriented question.

Answer (score 3):

The final part of your question was:

> What I really need is something powerful enough to break through the "This process has worked for 20 years, why should we change it?" argument.

You are trying to win an argument.  This is something that is particular to you and the person you are trying to persuade.

There's a comment on this question which is key to understanding why this was closed (realizing that

> recommended reading: [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6629/how-do-i-explain-something-to-someone/6630#6630) –  gnat 15 hours ago

This particular suggestion is one that I am quite familiar with, though one of the things you are trying to do isn't covered in that answer (I'll have to see about updating it).  You are asking for a list of bullet points of ammunition (pun intended) for your argument.  I'll point to [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) which tries to address polling type questions.

This type of question is a poll that can have dozens of answers, none of which are 'right'.  I'll draw your attention to a comment in the "How do I explain..." meta post:

> If you look at this you'll see an example of "how to win an argument" - and there are numerous ones of these, and we tend to want to avoid this with its 20+ answers with no 'right' answer. "I thought of another example", "I haven't really thought it out"

The original links have been cleaned up by the roomba, so [Arguments for or against using Try/Catch as logical operators](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/107723/40980) (and thank you for having me find that question, there's a close vote on it now too).  And while this may be what you are looking for, it really works against the Q&A style format that Stack Exchange is trying to promote.  I'll point out that several of the answers have comments that have devolved into discussions.

Now, why its opinion rather than too broad?  That's just what people clicked on at least three times when closing the question.