# Why is this question locked?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, locked-question

This question shows up in the [10k delete review list](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tools) because it has a delete vote cast:

[How do I explain a “Hello World” program for beginners? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/135925/22815)

The question is a classic example of [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6629/22815) and as such was rightfully closed.

Why does this question have a historical lock (by [maple_shaft](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/25476/maple-shaft))? Should we unlock it and delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've deleted it as it seemed to have minimal redeeming value.

Comment: +1 'cause I can't thank you more than that (exploring historical locks and +1ing correct deletions)

Answer (score 2):

I can only speculate, but it did have 5,000+ views so perhaps maple_shaft thought it was worth locking for that reason.

If something, while being off topic, is popular (looking at its age, votes and views) then we do consider locking rather than deleting. This is so that we preserve any incoming links.

This was probably a borderline case, *almost* enough views to warrant keeping around, but ultimately probably not worth keeping.

Comment: I agree that off-topic but useful questions _may_ merit a lock, but that question was not "useful" even if it had a million views. Regardless, it appears that we reached a consensus and the appropriate action was taken.

Comment: @Snowman - indeed. I was just pointing out the thought processes that *might* have gone into locking rather than deleting.