# What happened to this question

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I came across this question yesterday: [I spend more time thinking about implementation rather than actually writing code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/384182).

It had a great success. Lots of views and votes and was even featured on SE Hot Questions.

Through the answers I found some really inspirational advice that already helped me in my work and to see things from another perspective (e.g. "[Always. Be. Shipping.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/yes-but-what-have-you-done/)").

But today I see the question is gone. Has it been deleted? Moved to another SE site (e.g. The Workplace)? It says "for reasons of moderation" but I don't understand what the problem could be.

I don't think it's a duplicate of [this question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8350) like user gnat suggested. It doesn't concern *my* question and apart from a message that said the question was deleted, there's no explanation. If I were the author I think I would have got some info about the deletion.

Comment: with regards to "great success", see also: [Recent Trouble With Popularity](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7525/31260)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it was deleted.

It is an example of a question that is blatantly off-topic. Because it already attracted answers, there is no way to edit the question to put it in a good form that would be suitable. Deletion discourages people from trying to ask similar questions in the future - people have regularly pointed to closed (and even locked) questions as being acceptable.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation :-)